Adding extra vertical lines in a HorizontalLineChart in Python ReportLab
Produced a standard temperature/time graph and incorporated it into an illustration.
  dwg = Drawing()
...
  myChart = HorizontalLineChart()
...
  dwg.add(myChart)

Under specific datacircumstances, I must add draw vertical to the chart.
Is it not possible to complete it on the chart? Should it be done on the DWG and if so, how?
